# Using lock in an async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have some doubts whether the "library" method below will actually work, or eventually deadlock.

I have an "old" object which needs to be protected, and "***lock***" seems to be the best tool, given that there are some reentrant calls to this resource (*SomeSharedResource*) throughout the "class".

**EDIT:**

1.) Will a call to "Compute" actually block or worse case deadlock?

```
var finalResult = await Compute(3).ConfigureAwait(false); // will this block?
```

2.) How about if someone did this?

```
 var finalResult = Compute(3).Result; // will this block/deadlock?
```

3.) 2 Threads calling at the same time:

```
 var finalResult = await Compute(3).ConfigureAwait(false); // will this block?
```

The method in question:

```
private readonly object lockObject = new object();
private async Task<double> Compute(int input)
{
    double result;
    lock (lockObject) {
        result = SomeSharedResource(input);
    }

   return  await ComputeAsync(result).ConfigureAwait(false); // some other awaitable method

}
```

Comment: deadlock will only happen when you have two locks. when first lock is locked at second object and second lock is locked at first object. there is no way to cause dead lock here. (correct me if im wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A call to `Compute(int input)` can certainly block. You `lock (lockobject)` in a synchronous manner. If one thread holds lockObject and another attempts to a acquire it, the second thread will block while waiting for the first thread to finish.
2. This can block for the same reason as #1. It will not deadlock based on what we see here because the result continuation does not inherit a synchronization context. It will also block waiting synchronously for the result of `ComputeAsync()` because it uses `.Result`
3. This can block for the same reason as #1.

Locks and continuations are different concepts. While I can't promise you that your program won't deadlock, it's because I can't see your entire program. Nothing that you've shown here is begging to deadlock (typical caveats re: `.Result` aside, of course).

But recognize that the presence of a lock() is practically advertising the possibility of a blocked thread of execution. The `async`-`await` keywords don't do anything magical with a lock in some synchronously executed code.

Answer (score 2):

None of these questions have actual answers. The answers to them all are "yes, they can deadlock, given sufficient operating conditions".

If you mean "will the `lock` statement cause blocking or deadlock?", then the answer is yes for the blocking and no for the deadlock (assuming `SomeSharedResource(input)` is well-behaved, i.e., doesn't deadlock internally).

Answer (score 1):

For questions 1, 2 and 3 the answer is, *"They probably won't deadlock"*.  Though, multiple simultaneous calls to a `lock` section WILL BLOCK, since they cannot be executed simultaneously, that does not mean they will **deadlock**.

You need to inspect what is happening inside the `lock` to determine that.

The danger is if a function inside the `lock` spawns a blocking asynchronous call (`await` or equivalent) that ends up calling back to `Compute()` or other code that also locks on `lockObject`.

As long as none of the functions inside the `lock` are blocking for another thread, you should be safe.  If there were blocking asynchronous calls, you would need to validate that they don't reenter, or make sure not to block on them.

Here are some examples of what to do, and NOT to do:

```cs
private async Task<double> DoSomething()
{
    return await Compute(0);
}

private readonly object lockObject = new object();
private async Task<double> Compute(int input)
{
    double result;
    lock (lockObject) {
        //This would be bad.
        result = await DoSomething();

        //So would this.  If you didn't wait inside the lock you wouldn't deadlock though.
        var t = DoSomething();
        result = t.Result;

        //This would be okay because it doesn't call back to Compute()
        using (var stream = File.OpenText("test.txt"))
        {
            var contents = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

   return  await ComputeAsync(result).ConfigureAwait(false); // some other awaitable method

}
```